# Visual Studio browser link is grayed out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I'm using visual studio 2013, and web essentials 1.1.

I'm trying to use browser link, but the button for it is greyed out in Visual Studio.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yfJjO5G.png]

Any idea how I can enable it?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have this setting in your `Web.config` file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

or debug to false?

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

source: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have either of these settings set.  
Browser link also works for my co-workers for this same project, which we share through TFS.  
+1 though, as it's good information that may help others in the future.

Comment: do you use the final version? or preview or release candidate? and what browser(s) do you have and is javascript enabled? perhaps upgrade 1.1 to 1.3.1 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361

Comment: I have the final ultimate version of VS, have the latest web essentials, and I've tried selecting chrome IE and firefox all to no avail. JavaScript is enabled on all of them, but the icon is grayed out so I don't think I'm getting far enough for that to be a problem.

Comment: Do you use IIS or IIS Express or development server (cassini)? and is your webserver on the localhost?

Comment: And is it specific for this vs solution, or also for other solutions?

Comment: It's just for this solution and I'm using iis express on localhost.

Comment: A wild guess, but do you have the nuget package glimpse installed? https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/526

Answer (score 0):

Check if the solution root has a file named WebEssentials-Settings.json

From that file, you'll see something like this:

```
{
  "BrowserLink": {
    "CssIgnorePatterns": "bootstrap*; reset.css; normalize.css; jquery*; toastr*; foundation*; animate*; inuit*; elements*; ratchet*; hint*; flat-ui*; 960*; skeleton*",
    "EnableMenu": true,
    "EnablePixelPushing": true,
    "ShowMenu": false
  },
  /* further settings down below */
}
```

Notice you have 2 settings. `EnableMenu` and `ShowMenu`. I had the same issue as you are having and I got `ShowMenu: false` while `EnableMenu: true`. I changed both to true, reopened the solution and it worked.