# "Refresh Linked Browsers" menu option is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, browser-link

I have enabled browser link, and I can see the Browser Link menu item, but the option "Refresh Linked Browsers" is greyed out.

[image]

In order to try to enable this option, I followed the steps described in the following article:

[Using Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)

but they did not make a difference. To clarify, based on the advise given in the article:

> To enable Browser Link, set debug=true in the <compilation> element in
>   the project’s Web.config file.

We have `debug=true` set in the web.config file.

> The application must be running on localhost.

The app is running in IIS on my PC.

> The application must target .NET 4.0 or later.

The target framework for the app is 4.5.2.

Are there other steps I need to take?

I did read the following:

[Visual Studio browser link is grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547744/visual-studio-browser-link-is-grayed-out)

But none of the answers resolved my issue.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I re-installed vs and now opening a asp.net 5 project I cant get that to enable or the ctrl+alt+enter to save and refresh

Comment: No, I've not figured out a way to enable that link. This is very annoying, since browser link + Web Essentials ability to inspect web page elements, and take me to the cshtml file where that element lives, is super handy.

Comment: Yes its extremely annoying, I have another machine that works just perfectly fine.   I am going to completely remove visual studio and try installing it again, hopefully that fixes it.  If not I am not even sure where to log this bug, either with asp.net group or vs group

Comment: It might be worth creating a bug report. You might get a reply which amount to workarounds that you can try, which may not be document elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was able to solve the problem by changing the output type in property -> Application. For an obscur reason, it was set to Console Application, whereas ASP.NET applications needs to be DLLs.